# Unit Test existing UI code

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, user-interface, mfc

I was browsing for a while the internet and this site and instead of finding some ways to unit test my existing code the only finding was to separate logic and interaction with the user (MVC approach). Although this is great for new projects it is time-consuming and as a result too expensive to invest for existing ones. Is there a way to create specific unit tests, ideally automated, for existing GUI projects that unfortunately connect directly to databases or other systems to get data and the data are manipulated before it is shown? Currently we have two projects the one being MFC, the other C# .net 2.0 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit testing won't cut in here considering you can't change your existing code (not to mention you don't really unit test UI). You should look for some kind of GUI testing automation/scripting tools. Like [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/). Quoting literally the first paragraph from their website:

> Sikuli is a visual technology to automate and test graphical user interfaces (GUI) using images (screenshots).

It doesn't get any simplier than that. You "tell" the tool which parts of your UI it should observe/interact, it records and replays it. Skimming through [this presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/vgod/practical-sikuli-using-screenshots-for-gui-automation-and-testing) will give you idea of what exactly you can do (might also check their video). Probably won't solve all your problems, but might be alternative worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing an already existing project is always a challenge. however i point you to some open source tools that will help you to automate unit testing

**C++**

[Boost unit test framework](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/utf/index.html)

[Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/)

**C#**

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/)

[NMock](http://nmock.org/)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to produce some level of automated testing, but not unit tests.

Unit tests, by definition, test small units of logic decoupled from the system as a whole. I'd recommend new code be written in the way you described (mvc etc) to be unit testable.

With your existing code, unit testing will obviously require refactoring, which I appreciate is not in your timeframe. You will need to work with what you've got an look at a way to perform more whole-system automated testing, probably driven through the UI. The fact these are not Unit tests is by-the-by, there are helpful tests to have even if you have unit tests. Its helpful to know the distinction though when you are searching for resources.

You are probably best searching for automated ui testing. With the .net apps, you may find something like [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) useful

Answer (score 1):

If you are lucky enough to have a Premium (at least) version of Visual Studio 2010, then you could consider writing [Coded UI Tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx).

A UI Test is basically an automated sequence of actions (mouse, keyboard...) on a GUI. These are very high level tests (or functional tests), not unit tests, but it can help testing a GUI application that is already existing.

For instance you can easily automate CRUD actions (which imply a database) and check (assert) that actions have produce the expected result in the UI (new created item in a list...).

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately we are using VS 05 for C# and VS 97 MFC :)

Answer (score 1):

Write UI testing can be **very** time consuming because there are various aspect you had to test. Thanks God there are a lot of frameworks to achieve that result but you always have to write some code.

**I assume you already did unit testing** (Visual Studio itself comes with a not so bad unit test framework) so what you want to check is not algorithms but UI automation/results. What does it mean? Everything that is *code* must be tested by code (database operations and algorithms, for example). Even some UI controls can be somehow tested by code (example: if I simulate a user click I'll get that event fired when this condition is true). Trust me, UI testing is Black Art and often you'll get failed tests even if everything is OK.

### Simple stress scenario

For a simple scenario, for example to stress your application to reproduce a bug repeating the same operation many times, you can use a macro recorder (such as [WinMacro](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cts=1331284974997&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://winmacro.codeplex.com/&ei=6stZT9TQNYPsOeTf8JkN&usg=AFQjCNHjKnti5Fp7Rr5CnLnLajOQQXjsQw&sig2=02URVzpxZc6KmYw-pTrwmw)). You register user inputs and then you run that macro in a loop. If there's a subtle bug you have many chances to reproduce (and/or to find) it when that actions are repeated 5000 times in a night. That done you'll get data from your logs.

### Simple scenario

If your application can be somehow automated (it may be easy for .NET application using [VSA](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9699/VSA-Scripting-in-NET)) you can prepare some "good" macro to automate an operation, put results in a file and compare them with a known good results data file.

Simple tip: for MFC application you can write your own "macro" with a text file where each line is a Windows message with its parameter; read it, parse it and `SendMessage()` them to your application to simulate user inputs, menu clicks and so on. Grab - for example - text box value and compare with something known. WinSpy++ is your friend.

### Complex scenario

For anything else (is my custom control drawing everything in the right way? when user click that button then UI colors changes?) you have to use a more complex tool. There are several tools to automate UI testing, built-in in Visual Studio 2010 (not in every edition) what you need to create *coded UI tests*. What does it mean? You write code to automate your application and then you write more code to check its results (sometimes even comparing *bitmaps* with known results. It may be tedious and a lot but virtually you can test everything, even if the application hasn't been designed for UI testing.
Start reading this from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286726.aspx).

There is a plethora of commercial tools too (even if I never used it in any project) so I not write any link, I guess you'll have a lot of results in Google.

Answer (score 1):

Mocking is usually the best approach for simulating integration points, but unfortunately most Mocking frameworks fall short if the code is too interconnected and bury dependencies in private methods etc.

It might be worth looking into a framework called Moles (made by Microsoft) that have very few limitations for what you can Mock. It even handles private methods!
Perhaps you could use it to mock your db calls to test your data manipulation? 
There are several tutorials online. 
Here's one that might get you started:
http://www.unit-testing.net/CurrentArticle/How-To-Mock-Code-Dependencies-Using-Moles.html