# Automate test from an existing java project

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, intellij-idea, automated-tests

I'm looking for a way to do a Unit tests on an existing project (`java project`).
I read `the legacy code book`. It advance to do some `refactoring method`, because the Unit tests on an existing project are consuming.
Honestly speaking, the project is big one. I found a question in stackoverflow :
[Unit Test existing UI code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9631524/unit-test-existing-ui-code)

I'm trying to find the best solution from it.
Another way that I found it, is on `Intellij IDE`, we can add a plugin `JUnit5` https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea/

We create a test case on each package or module. I started creating the unit test classes, I found a lot of `errors, warnings, deprecated frameworks`. But, it's consuming a lot.
I'm looking again for a solution. In the meanwhile, please can some one suggest a solution, idea to automate unit tests on an existing java project ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All current Java IDEs have JUnit 5 built in, so no need to add a plugin. Automate unit tests? What exactly do you want to automate? Eclipse's cleanup functions might be helpful for your legacy project (select the project and choose _Source > Clean Up..._).

Comment: What were the "errors, warnings, deprecated frameworks"? Eclipse already supports and includes JUnit, but it's not automatically included in every Java project.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution to the problem that writing (good) unit tests is time consuming .... there isn't one.   If you are looking for a magic tool that is going to fix errors, warnings, use of deprecated frameworks .... there isn't one.

Comment: The code is already written without any Unit tests. And, it's already in production. So, I have to create a unit test for all methods, classes, etc.... For this reasons I'm looking for a way how can I do that. I know, there's nothing is magic, but, the solutions are exist. If, I use Eclipse (Source > Clean Up....) is this solution will create a unit test cases ?

Comment: _Source > Clean Up..._ does not create unit tests, but cleans up the code, which would be error-prone and time-consuming being done manually. What is the purpose of adding unit tests (to find bugs that haven't been detected yet, or to make manual changes more safe, ...)? Please describe the manual steps you want to automate with an example.

Comment: *"But, it's consuming a lot."* **--** What exactly does that mean? If it means "lots of effort to write those tests" then here is the bad news: this effort cannot be reduced. Someone simply has to write them...